# Dropdown в тегах li с разным id срабатывает одновременно

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap

`Dropdown` в тегах `li` с разным `id`  срабатывает одновременно при нажатии на одну либо на другую кнопку.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">


<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<div class="col-md-8 col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-lg-8 ">
                <ul class="header-menu">
                    <li class=" dropdown"
                        type="button" id="catalog"
                        data-toggle="dropdown"
                        aria-expanded="false">
                        каталог
                    </li>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu " aria-labelledby="catalog" >
                        <li><a  href="#">наименование</a></li>
                        <li><a  href="#">наименование</a></li>
                        <li><a  href="#">наименование</a></li>
                        <li><a  href="#">наименование</a></li>
                    </div>
                    <li class=" dropdown"
                        type="button" id="info"
                        data-toggle="dropdown"
                        aria-expanded="false">
                        информация
                    </li>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu " aria-labelledby="info" >
                        <li><a  href="#">info</a></li>
                        <li><a  href="#">info</a></li>
                    </div>
                    <li ><a href="#">блог</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"> контакты</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
```

Comment: Смотря что у вас в onclick на ваши кнопки.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Потому что не к списку, а к ссылке или кнопке применяется дропдаун и не `dropdown`, а `dropdown-toggle` + список оборачивается в тег `ul`, а не в `div`:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  
<div class="row">  
  <div class="col-md-8 col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-lg-8 ">
    <ul class="header-menu">
      <li>
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle"
            type="button" id="catalog"
            data-toggle="dropdown"
            aria-expanded="false">
          каталог
        </a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="catalog" >
          <li><a  href="#">наименование</a></li>
          <li><a  href="#">наименование</a></li>
          <li><a  href="#">наименование</a></li>
          <li><a  href="#">наименование</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      
      <li>
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle"
            type="button" id="info"
            data-toggle="dropdown"
            aria-expanded="false">
          информация
        </a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu " aria-labelledby="info" >
          <li><a  href="#">info</a></li>
          <li><a  href="#">info</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      
      <li ><a href="#">блог</a></li>
      <li><a href="#"> контакты</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

P.S: В bootstrap есть же примеры. Или можно [посмотреть на w3school примеры](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_dropdowns.asp).